# jquery delay reload of layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery Social Stream on the following page: http://lightmodels.co.uk/light-models-social-networking.html

The problem is once the images have loaded the panels overlap. It has been suggested that the following code is used after a delay `jQuery(’.stream’).isotope(‘reLayout’);`

I have no jQuery skills so I'm not sure if this would work, how to implement it and where to put it? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Isotope is unable to calculate the correct heights when the image is not yet loaded. Usually you solve this by verifying that all images is loaded ([described here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html)) before you initiate the Isotope plugin.

I don't know how the social stream works so I can't answer regarding if it's possible to do the same in this case.

As you mentioned in your question, it's possible to call the "layout" method to force Isotope to recalculate the elements but this is not a good solution.

CODE:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#social-stream').find('.stream').isotope('layout');
}, 2000); // Recalculates the layout after 2 sec
```